# Accept Outlook calendar invites on behalf of other user

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange, calendar

I am using Exchange 2003 with Outlook 2007 and I am hoping to set up a rule so that any calendar invites sent to another user will go to my inbox and not the users, allowing me to accept/decline the invite which will then update the users' calendar.

Is this possible within Outlook?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you basically want to force users to accept your meetings? Doesn't sound very ethical if that is the case.

Comment: @EricF That is quite an assumption on your part. I don't read the question that way. How does your comment help the community of Super User?

Comment: That is why I asked. Thanks for your help though Charlie. I am glad to have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to having `Delegate access` to someone's calendar. This function is available in Outlook, but needs to be setup on each person's account.

> A delegate manages someone else's schedule, meetings, and
>   appointments, freely and visibly.

Here is a short course on how to do this - [Delegate Access: Let someone else mind your calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/delegate-access-let-someone-else-mind-your-calendar-RZ010356026.aspx)

> Delegation involves (at least) two people. We assume that you're
>   taking this course with sharing in mind, and that you have someone in
>   mind to share with. If you can, take this course along with that
>   person. The two of you can do the practices together and experience
>   delegate access in action.